# How to make one column flexible with window and other column to be fixed in listview?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list view of 3 columns in which I need 2 columns to be of fixed width and one of them to be flexible with window size.
Which is by the way not possible with any of the ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle which specifies only ColumnHeader Content Width and None.

**|Column 1(Fixed)|<----Column 2 (Flexible)---->|Column3(Fixed)|**

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it by c# through some coding for changing width of column during window resize

```
// First Initiate the fixed columns with the 
public void FormConstructor
{
     InitializeComponent();
     listView.Columns[0].AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);         
     listView.Columns[2].AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);

     //OR

     listView.Columns[0].Width = 100;
     listView.Columns[2].Width = 200;
}

// Event on WindowSizechanged
private void Form_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView.Columns[1].Width = listView.Width - listView.Columns[0].Width - 
                                listView.Columns[2].Width;
}
```